# Injecting headers into Silverlight without WCF

Tags: silverlight, soap

Ive been trying to figure this one out for a while. I need to be able to inject a username and password into a soap message header, without the use of WCF. I'm hoping there is a method that doesn't require me to either rewrite the service reference or have to write my own custom requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/03/15/username-password-amp-ws-security-with-silverlight.aspx

This blog gave me the information on how to inject a header without WCF.